# "undefined is not an object", need to check if allNotes array is empty. How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Feel like this is kind of a silly question but I need to only return the allNotes map data if allNotes isn't empty (its an array). This seems like just a simple if/else but really can't figure out how to do this in this context (inside view). Right now, I get the error in the title when nothing is in the array. when it has data everything is fine.

```
{isOpen &&
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateDrop(prev => !prev)} style={styles.flastListUpdated}>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={styles.flastlistItemText2}>{props.noteitem.note}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'lightgrey' }} />

                    <View>

                        {allNotes.map((item) => {

                            return (
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', margin: 5 }}>
                                    <View style={styles.perItemBar} />
                                    <Text style={styles.noteTextStyle}>{item}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )

                        })}

                        <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
                            <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => { updateNoteStatus(text) }} style={{ flex: 2 }} placeholder='Enter New:' />
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={addNote} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>+</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        </View>
    )

}
```

Again I Know this is something really simple but I can't get the formatting correct. Don't know what the correct method of doing this would be. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show where you define `allNotes`?

Comment: `allNotes` sounds like it is undefined, _not_ an empty array. Now, assuming that's the "valid" value when it's "empty", it'd be easy to coalesce it to an empty array.. and iterating an empty array is effectively a no-op.

Comment: all notes is defined at the global level in the component. Looks like this  " let allNotes = props.noteitem.notes"

Comment: `undefined` is a value, not necessarily "not declared / not assigned". If `props.noteitem.notes` has the value `undefined`, this would be expected. If `props[.noteitem]` comes from JSON, for example, missing properties will return `undefined`. IMOHO, the cleanest method is to fix this data-model at point of introduction. eg. `props.noteitem.notes ||= []` somewhere in the access layer; or otherwise _actually_ return an empty array from the server/source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could always double check that allNotes is defined like this although it may be better to default allNotes to an empty array and then confirm here that it's what you'd expect.

```
{isOpen &&
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateDrop(prev => !prev)} style={styles.flastListUpdated}>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={styles.flastlistItemText2}>{props.noteitem.note}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'lightgrey' }} />

                    <View>

                        {allNotes && allNotes.map(item => (
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', margin: 5 }}>
                                    <View style={styles.perItemBar} />
                                    <Text style={styles.noteTextStyle}>{item}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        )}

                        <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
                            <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => { updateNoteStatus(text) }} style={{ flex: 2 }} placeholder='Enter New:' />
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={addNote} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>+</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```